# limiting the number of character in GUID

Tags: c#-4.0, guid

is it possible or is there any overload to get a less than 32 characters of GUID ?
currently i am using this statement but its giving me error

```
string guid = new Guid("{dddd-dddd-dddd-dddd}").ToString();
```

i want a key of 20 characters

Comment: If it had less characters, it wouldn't be a GUID. It would be some other not-so-random value.

Comment: Check out this answer to get it down to 20 characters using Ascii85 encoding: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3247983/945456

Comment: Do you want a GUID or do you want a 20 character value?  They're not the same.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a ShortGuid. [Here is an example](http://www.singular.co.nz/blog/archive/2007/12/20/shortguid-a-shorter-and-url-friendly-guid-in-c-sharp.aspx) of an implementation.

It's nice to use ShortGuids in URLs or other places visible to an end user.

The following code:

```
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
ShortGuid sguid1 = guid; // implicitly cast the guid as a shortguid
Console.WriteLine( sguid1 );
Console.WriteLine( sguid1.Guid );
```

Will give you this output:

```
FEx1sZbSD0ugmgMAF_RGHw
b1754c14-d296-4b0f-a09a-030017f4461f
```

This is the code for an Encode and Decode method:

```
public static string Encode(Guid guid)
{
   string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(guid.ToByteArray());
   encoded = encoded
     .Replace("/", "_")
     .Replace("+", "-");
   return encoded.Substring(0, 22);
}

public static Guid Decode(string value)
{
   value = value
     .Replace("_", "/")
     .Replace("-", "+");
   byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(value + "==");
   return new Guid(buffer);
}
```

Comment: This is 22 characters.  The question states he wants 20 characters.  You need to step up from BASE64 to ASCII85 to shave those 2 off.  See David's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use Jeff Attwood's ASCII85...

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/10/equipping-our-ascii-armor.html
and
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/10/c-implementation-of-ascii85.html