# Varchar character length

Tags: mysql, database

I want to store an unique ID in my MySQL databse, but I need to know how long the X in varchar(X) should be.

The character length I need is 36 characters, example of an unique ID I use: 883db600-3512-4124-8cd5-5bd051f137fe

Comment: It seems you're using UUID, so I would use `CHAR(36)` because the length will not change and you'd be storing that data together with the rest of your row data which should improve the performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is always 36 characters long then use

```
char(36)
```

if it can be shorther then

```
varchar(36)
```

Comment: It should always be 36 characters long, I'll use char(36). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A typical guid is 38 bytes (if you are counting the curlies).

More info: [How many characters are there in a GUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607651/how-many-characters-are-there-in-a-guid)

char(38) or char(36)